# Use django-crispy-forms with Uikit

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, getuikit

I'm building a website with django and i'm using uikit 3 as front-end framework is there any way to style django-crispy-forms with uikit ? 
with bootstrap i can just put this line on settings file :

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

is their any option like this to use uikit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check the documentation of the packages you use:

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#template-packs

> Since version 1.1.0, django-crispy-forms has built-in support for
>   different CSS frameworks, known as template packs within
>   django-crispy-forms:
>
> - bootstrap Bootstrap is crispy-forms’s default template pack, version 2 of the popular simple and flexible HTML, CSS, and Javascript
>     for user interfaces from Twitter.
> - bootstrap3 Twitter Bootstrap version 3.
> - bootstrap4 Alpha support for Twitter Bootstrap version 4, which is still in Alpha.
> - uni-form Uni-form is a nice looking, well structured, highly customizable, accessible and usable forms.
> - foundation Foundation In the creator’s words, “The most advanced responsive front-end framework in the world.” This template pack is
>     externally available through crispy-forms-foundation